# How do i get old external drive data onto new external drive (but not also on computer HD)

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup, ssd, external-disk

EDIT:Let me try again.
Sorry guys I'm fairly adept at understanding things in regards to these machines, but I'm by no means a pro. Just looking for some advice.

MacBook Pro 2007 ==> Backed up to G Drive Q (500Gb)External HD.
I keep my music mp3s (iTunes is targeted to this drive), and my  Time Machine backups on here.

G Drive Q (500GB) quits. Disk won't mount, can't be seen in Finder or Time machine or Disk Utility.

MacBook Pro 2007 died.

Purchase MacBook Pro 2012 and get LaCie 1TB External SSD from a friend.

MacBook Pro 2012 ==> backed up to LaCie 1TB External SSD.

A friend gives me an enclosure for G Drive Q (500GB), It mounts when plugged into MacBook 2012. Great. Restored  desktop/ everything that was actually on MacBook Pro 2007 Made sure I could go in and pull files back onto my computer through Time Machine. Did this manually with my financials that were on the G Drive Q (500GB), and a few important files.

So I want to get the stuff from Grive Q (500GB) Drive Q (onto LaCie 1TB External SSD to use for the same purpose, storing music and  Time Machine backups.

So this is where i tried to use Migration Assistant.  I somehow got a second user (which i think just reinstalled everything from MacBook 2007 a second time).

None of my old Time Machine backups appeared on my computer ( i thought this would work to then  just re -back up), and i could not drag to copy them onto LaCie 1TB External SSD. Shitty. Had trouble finding the right advice in forums. Pretty sure i just put my old computer on my new computer twice. Could not figure out how to get old backups from G Drive Q (500GB) to LaCie 1TB External SSD.

So I went by a year, backing up MacBook Pro 2012 onto LaCie 1TB External SSD with Time Machine.

LaCie 1TB External SSD  USB connection accidentally gets knocked loose, it corrupts. Kaput.

Now as I was just using it (LaCie 1TB External SSD) for Time machine backups, and have not deleted anything off my MacBook Pro 2012 HD, I figure it is moot.

Just purchased WD Elements 2TB External.

What I am hoping:

-To get the music and Time Machine backups off the  G Drive Q (500GB), and onto WD Elements 2TB External.

-To use WD Elements 2TB External to continue Time machine backups.

-To eliminate second user that was created on MacBook 2012, and free up disk space it is occupying. (I'm pretty certain it's redundant, and like 200GB i could free up).

Hope this is clearer, any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

K

I had an old 500GB GQ external that i used to back up my old macbook pro (2007), that drive became inaccessible, then my macbook pro failed. I got a new macbook pro (2012), and a solid state 1TB. on both these machines i used time machine every month or so manually for backups. The A friend of mine gave me an enclosure for my old 500GB GQ, and it worked. Great. I wanted to find a way to get the backups from the old external to the new one, but could not copy them over, I had to re-instate them through time machine. I tried using Migration assistant, but that just created a new user..the solid state 1TB has since corrupted when it accidentally got unplugged. inaccessible. I just purchased a WD 2TB solid state. 
Question: Is there a way to get my old (5ooGB GQ backups) onto my new external (2TB) drive so that they can be accessible through time machine? as i haven't deleted anything since i got the new computer, I'm not worried about stuff lost on the 1TB ssd that corrupted, but do want to back up soon, and back up the stuff on the original external. I'd also like to delete the second user account that the migration assistant created when i did that before, as I'm fairly certain i just used up a bunch of hard drive space on my computer HD that Is not necessary. Or is Time machine built in such a way that you need to have different users for different hard drive records? very confused. To re-iterate: Would like my old data available on new drive (though not on computer - i store my music, old art projects, recording projects etc), as well as current back ups, for obvious reasons, and eliminate the huge data that exists on a second user i don't think i need.

THoughts? maybe i need a diagram..

Kev

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://eshop.macsales.com/tech_center/index.cfm?page=/manuals/mac/clon_data.html) describes how to clone a drive using Disk Utility.

In essence, you mount both drives on your system, select the new drive and choose restore, then select the old drive as the source and make a cup of coffee (500 GiB could take an hour or two, depending on you exact setup).

Comment: My apologies for not answering the second part of your question. You can format the drive before migrating to erase anything on there. This will happen when you restore the drive anyway, though.

Comment: Thank you!This makes sense to me. But if i restore from the old drive, it is only restoring to the new external, correct? It won't reset anything on my laptop HD...? Then once that is in place i should just be able to back up laptop HD to that same drive, and should have Time Machine access to everything?

Comment: Correct. The data will move from the old HDD to the new one without being left on your Mac.

Comment: Great news. Thanks so much. Any thoughts on deleting a second user? I tried to describe it a little better in my edit up top, Im pretty sure when i tried to do the external copy (wrong, with Migration assistant), before on another drive (that is since then kaput),  after using Migration Assistant properly to re-install my last system backup from old computer.  , I just re-installed my former computer on my new computer twice.  Pretty sure it is just eating up HD space on my current computer.

Comment: ...You might have answered this but I'm not quite clear, sorry!

Comment: Your questions are fairly difficult to follow, try specifying "HDD A" and "HDD B" etc. To answer you question (I think) formatting a drive will completely erase any data previously on it, as will using the method above to restore a backup image (or simply migrate a drive).